# James Bond must Go!

Tags: story

Once I was flirting with the receptionist at the gym.  She marveled at my international business travel and  I joked I was Bond, James Bond.  She laughed... and instead of a locker key she handed me a key to the loo!  What gives?

Comment: Should this puzzle have the "language" tag?

Comment: Were you about to pass a Thunderball?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If the key had a keychain tag marked **LOO**, upside down it could be read as **007**. Or, it's actually 007 and you are reading it upside down.

Comment: the second of those, and btw this is a true story